# Is a Microsoft account necessary for viewing shared Teams meeting recordings?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-account, sharing

I recorded a Teams meeting in my organization (there were people joined from outside my organization, if that matters). I then shared the recording with several people, including some outside my organization. One outside user says they cannot view it, as they do not have a Microsoft account. Is a MS account indeed necessary for viewing? When I look in **Advanced settings** for the recording, I see the message, *Open to anyone with a guest link*. Does that mean that the recording should work for anyone who has the link URL?

Comment: "Does that mean that the recording should work for anyone who has the link URL?" - If the user is not part of your organization, and based on the fact they currently do not have acces sto the file, your organization's Administrator likely has not allowed anyone from outside your organization to access the files.  So the statement with regards to access is limited to users with the link AND are within your organization. You should contact your system Administrator for details and restrictions on sharing files to users outside of your organization.